# « Special Issue: Joe Easton – Engineering Scientist. Celebrating his 70th Anniversary »

Tags: traduction, anglais, usage, académique

Comment rendre en français la phrase :

> Special Issue: Joe Easton – Engineering Scientist. Celebrating his 70th Anniversary

vue, par ex. ici : https://link.springer.com/journal/419/84/9

ou bien ici : https://www.sciencedirect.com/journal/international-journal-of-non-linear-mechanics/vol/36/issue/3

La traduction :

> Numéro spécial: Joe Easton - Ingénieur scientifique. Célébrant son 70<sup>e</sup> anniversaire

est-elle correcte ?

Questions spécifiques :

1. « Ingénieur scientifique » rend-il correctement le sens d'*Engineering Scientist* ?
2. « Numéro spécial » rend-il le sens de *Special Issue* (d'une revue scientifique) ?
3. « Célébrant son 70<sup>e</sup> anniversaire » serait-il compris ?

Comment: 'Anniversary' est un choix étrange : pour les personnes on dit 'birthday'. 'Anniversary' est utilisé pour des événements (par ex. anniversaire de mariage, ou grande promo pour les 5 ans d'un centre commercial). Mon premier réflexe est : anniversaire de _quoi_ ?

Comment: _Engineering_ qualifie _scientist_, c'est probablement [_scientifique en génie](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&srchtxt=ENGINEERING+SCIENTIST&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs)/ingénierie_...

Comment: @MathieuBouville La tournure est rencontrée souvent en anglais.

Comment: https://books.google.fr/books?id=IRzoCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA558&lpg=PA558&dq=elasticity+70th+anniversary&source=bl&ots=YfetwMVoDe&sig=ACfU3U0m_IYN0GIisF9heuTax7XB-dGHYw&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwje3OPjpZvhAhUDWxoKHTRqCswQ6AEwAHoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=elasticity%2070th%20anniversary&f=false

Comment: @MathieuBouville https://www.sciencedirect.com/journal/international-journal-of-non-linear-mechanics/vol/36/issue/3

Comment: @Stephane Je viens d'éditer la question.

Comment: 1. Non, 2. Oui, 3. Compris, mais pas terrible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La  traduction suivante, qui nous vient du traducteur DeepL, me semble convenir ;

> Numéro spécial : Joe Easton - Ingénieur scientifique. Fête de son 70e anniversaire

Comment: Merci. Au lieu du participe passe, un nom (plus un complément du nom). Pourquoi ?

Comment: @Dimitris On rend le gérondif de diverses manières mais souvent par un infinitif ; par exemple on utilise l'infinif ici : "Speaking while chewing some bread isn't easy." ==> Parler en machant du pain n'est pas facile. L'infinitif a alors valeur de substantif en français; on peut aussi utiliser un substantif ; par exemple le contexte suivant ses prête très bien aux deux possibilités;« Shaving with ease ! » ==>  « Le rasage facile ! » *ou* « Se raser facilement ! ». (champ 1)

Comment: Noter que le gérondif a une valeur de substantif ; cependant dans l'énoncé ce n'est pas le cas et il s'agit du participe présent pur et simple dans une ellipse (We are celebrating) ; on traduit cela par « C'est la fête …» que l'on peut employer sous forme d'ellipse (Fête). On aurait pu dire aussi « Nous fêtons son 70e anniversaire. ».

Comment: @Dimitris Noter aussi que l'énoncé pourrait être compris comme l'ellipse de « He is celebrating his …» (ngram).